# How define regex to delete all between two characters

Tags: php, html, regex, string, replace

I have problem with definition of regex pattern. In code below I want to delete all `<p>` tags and all attributes between `<p >` like `style="bla bla"`, but I want keep other elements and their attributes like `<img>` in this case. I tried this pattern `/\<p.*?\>|\s*/` but it's not working for me. Can someone help me?

```
<p style="text-align: center;">LOREM IPSUMLOREM IPSUMLOREM IPSUMLOREM IPSUMLOREM IPSUM</p>
<p>
<img class="alignnone" src="http://localhost/themify/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/fortuna_novi-300x300.png" alt="fortuna_novi" width="112" height="112">
</p>
```

EDIT: I want to get result like this

```
LOREM IPSUMLOREM IPSUMLOREM IPSUMLOREM IPSUMLOREM IPSUM
<img class="alignnone" src="http://localhost/themify/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/fortuna_novi-300x300.png" alt="fortuna_novi" width="112" height="112">
```

Comment: you should add the expected result so that the question will be more clear

Comment: Don't use regex for DOM manipulation. You will save yourself from alot of trouble by just using a DOM parser.

Comment: @TingYiShih - Now I added result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following snippet may help you:

```
$re = "/(\\s*<p.*?\\s*>|<\\s*\\/p\\s*>)/"; 
$str = "<p style=\"text-align: center;\">LOREM IPSUMLOREM IPSUMLOREM IPSUMLOREM IPSUMLOREM IPSUM</p>\n<p>\n<img class=\"alignnone\" src=\"http://localhost/themify/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/fortuna_novi-300x300.png\" alt=\"fortuna_novi\" width=\"112\" height=\"112\">\n</p>"; 
$subst = "$1"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pT5iX7/1)

Answer (score 0):

See comment from EJTH and I can't repeat it too often: Don't use regex for DOM manipulation!

In this case, if you only want to remove all `<p>` and `</p>` tags, you could use something like

```
<p[^>]*>|</p>
```

This matches `<p`, any character but `>` (zero or more times) and a closing `>` *or* the literal `</p>`

If there occurs a literal `>` inside the attribute values (should not, but who knows), you might want to use a slightly more complex version like

```
<p(?:\s+\w+(="[^"]*"|'[^']*'|\w+)?)*>|</p>
```